# How to make whatsapp type of animation for opening the menu from toolbar(actionbar)

Tags: android, android-menu, whatsapp

### Description:

1. I recently updated whatsapp and noticed the
   animation for menu item clicked on toolbar. How to achieve this
   effect?
2. Are there any opensource projects to achieve this?
3. I have not posted any code because. I have no clue how they are doing
   it.

***Snapshot-1 : Before clicking the attachment button in menu***
[image: img]

---

***Snapshot-2 : After clicking the attachment button in menu***

[image: img2]

---

### How to Achieve this?

Comment: i think this will give you some hint http://blog.grafixartist.com/circular-reveal-effect-like-whatsapp-in-android/

Comment: Exactly!  http://pulse7.net/android/android-create-circular-reveal-animation-and-ripple-effect-like-whatsapp/

Answer (score 14):

Seems like they "ported" lollipop animation in pre-L devices. The simplest way to do this is using libraries like [Igvalle's Material-Animation](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations) (see #4). Its `minSdk` is 16, but I hope you can decrease it for 14 or below.

Some other libraries: [TransitionsBackport](https://github.com/guerwan/TransitionsBackport), [PreLollipopTransition](https://github.com/takahirom/PreLollipopTransition), [transitions-everywhere](https://github.com/andkulikov/transitions-everywhere).

Please let me know if you create this animation!

Comment: I have to say my github project is not really a library but an example of how to do this kind of animations :)